# What is the best practice for implementing multiple paths for one component in Vue router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

So, basically I'm learning Vue router and I have the following routes to navigate to the `HomeView` component:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import HomeView from '../views/HomeView.vue'

const routes = [
{
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: HomeView
  },
  {
    path: '/home',
    name: 'home',
    component: HomeView
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

And I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `alias` option ([docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#alias:%7E:text=%7D%2C%0A%5D-,Alias,-%23))

Example from the docs.

```js
   ...
   {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: HomeView,
    alias: '/home'
  },
   ...
```

From the docs:

> You can even combine both and provide multiple aliases with an array:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/users',
    component: UsersLayout,
    children: [
      // this will render the UserList for these 3 URLs
      // - /users
      // - /users/list
      // - /people
      { path: '', component: UserList, alias: ['/people', 'list'] },
    ],
  },
]
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all don't use the same name for 2 different routes. There are 2 methods call Redirect and Alias: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html

You can check them out. In my opinion Redirect method might make your code (in this case) more readable.

Example:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: { name: 'home' },
  },
  {
    path: '/home',
    name: 'home',
    component: HomeView,
  }
]
```

Comment: @Gass That's exactly what I meant, I just edited my answer. Nice work.